# Database link timed out on Oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I do encounter an issue with Oracle database 11g while trying to create a database link between two databases on the same server. I'm using SQL Developer 4.1.3.20 and the query that I use looks like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK TestKgu
CONNECT TO sys
IDENTIFIED BY *******
--USING '//10.0.9.8:1521/TCDB';
USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.0.9.8)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=TCDB)))';

COMMIT;

select * from v$version@TestKgu;

DROP DATABASE LINK TestKgu;
```

On Scriptout I get the following messages:

> Database link TESTKGU created.
>
> Commit finished.
>
> Database link TESTKGU deleted.

On the contrary the result output shows me the following messages:

> ORA-12170: TNS: Connect Timeout occurred
>
> 12170. 00000 -  "TNS:Connect timeout occurred"
>
> *Cause:    The server shut down because connection establishment or
>              communication with a client failed to complete within the allotted time
>              interval. This may be a result of network or system delays; or this may
>              indicate that a malicious client is trying to cause a Denial of Service
>              attack on the server.
>
> *Action:   If the error occurred because of a slow network or system,
>             reconfigure one or all of the parameters SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT,
>              SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT, SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT in sqlnet.ora to larger values.
>              If a malicious client is suspected, use the address in sqlnet.log to
>              identify the source and restrict access. Note that logged addresses may
>              not be reliable as they can be forged (e.g. in TCP/IP).
>
> Fehler in line: 9 column: 25

The user has CREATE DATABASE LINK privileg and the target database can be opened in SQL Developer and queries can be executed on the target database, too.

Both databases have the same version:

> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit
>
> Production PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production "CORE   11.2.0.4.0
>
> Production" TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
>
> NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 – Production

Is there a method to check if the database link can properly connect to the target database and give an error message if the link cannot connect?

Comment: 1) You can't create database links as sysdba (and sys always has to connect as sysdba).  2)  Sounds like your connect string is incorrect, try this on the database server: sqlplus <user>/<pass>@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.0.9.8)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=TCDB)))